# USB Backup Drive does not show up complete after a successful dd backup

Tags: backup

I performed a Server Backup (ubuntu 13.10) via dd onto an external USB-Drive. NO error messages.

```
sudo lshw -short
.

/0/1           scsi0      storage        
/0/1/0.0.0     /dev/sda   disk           500GB ST500LT012-9WS14
/0/1/0.0.0/1   /dev/sda1  volume         486MiB Windows FAT Laufwerk
/0/1/0.0.0/2   /dev/sda2  volume         244MiB EFI partition
/0/1/0.0.0/3   /dev/sda3  volume         465GiB LVM Physical Volume
/0/2           scsi6      storage        
/0/2/0.0.0     /dev/sdb   disk           1TB External USB 3.0
/0/2/0.0.0/1   /dev/sdb1  volume         486MiB Windows FAT Laufwerk
/0/2/0.0.0/2   /dev/sdb2  volume         244MiB EFI partition
/0/2/0.0.0/3   /dev/sdb3  volume         465GiB LVM Physical Volume
```

Unfortunately, I don't see the complete drive anymore on the Unity-desktop - only the part /dev/sdb2 as : Datenträger 256 MB
The same goes, if I klick to 'PERSONAL'
What am I doing wrong ?

---

I booted ubuntu from a USB-stick.
Via terminal I typed in

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdc
```

The complete internal drive was copied without error

Comment: What was the exact `dd` command you used?

Comment: @Jos See edit to the question.

Answer (score 1):

> USB Backup Drive does not show up complete after a successful dd backup

Don't do that, especially with lvm; use a proper backup method instead.  By copying the whole thing bit for bit, you now have two volumes that have the same UUID, and this makes them difficult or impossible to differentiate.  In the case of LVM, this may cause the system to sometimes mount the second disk instead and write your changes there, then you may shutdown, remove the external drive, start up again, and wonder why you "lost" files.